# Why Spark Streaming keeps all batches in memory?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wonder why Spark Streaming keeps all processed batches in memory? It leads to getting out of memory on executors but I really don't need them after processing. Can it be configured somewhere so that batches are not kept in memory after processing?

Comment: Could you add the code you're using? Window-based Spark Streaming operations do cache RDDs, but it's not a general policy.

Comment: @maasg actually it is fixed now. I restarted the job yesterday morning, so now it's up for 23 hours and there's no problem with memory. I can clearly see in executor's log that old RDDs are deleted. I also didn't change any configs. So now I'm gonna watch for it and if anything goes wrong and I'll figure out the problem, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

In one way, each batch of data is treated as an RDD, which is an immutable parallel collection of data, and they are saved in memory and replicated to several nodes for fault-tolerance.

In the other way, just in case that stateful operations have a dependency on previous batches of data.

Actually I don't really get your point, but I think spark streaming will eliminate old staled batches when necessary.

Comment: Thank for response! But the thing is that it doesn't eliminate old staled batches. After every processed batch I got the log message:
`15/11/19 11:11:14 INFO MemoryStore: Block input-0-1447931471000 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 44.9 KB, free 1017.2 MB)`
And the free space gets less and less within time. Eventually leading to running executor out of memory.

Comment: @Artem Well, maybe you can check these configs in your Spark and Spark Streamming. `spark.cleaner.ttl`、`spark.streaming.unpersist`、`spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`, just some persistent and gc related configs. Maybe help.

Comment: I already tried `spark.cleaner.ttl` but it cleaned all my broadcast vars :D Anyway I'll try other configs you mentioned. Thank you!